# Leaflet geojson update draggable state or marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I would like to know if it's possible to update the draggable event of a marker inside a GEOJSON layer in leaflet, I know I can do this by adding:

```
layer.options.draggable = True
```

Inside the onEachFeature function, what I'm trying to achieve is, to update the draggable options on an element click, something like:

```
$(document).on('click','#someButton',function(){
    layer.options.draggable = True; //Only one specific marker
});
```

This way I would like to have all my marker with draggable options disabled, then on a button click, enable the draggable option, only for one specific marker. Is it possible to achieve this using geojson layer? I also have this geojson layer inside a featureGroup, hope you guys can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically enable / disable the draggability of a Leaflet Marker by simply removing it from the map, setting (resetting) its [`draggable`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-draggable) option, then re-adding it to the map:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var marker = L.marker([48.86, 2.35]).addTo(map);

document.getElementById('dragonoff').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Toggle Marker draggability.
  marker.remove();
  marker.options.draggable = !marker.options.draggable;
  marker.addTo(map);

  alert(marker.options.draggable ? 'Marker is now draggable' : 'Marker is no longer draggable');
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 150px"></div>

<button id="dragonoff">Enable / Disable dragging</button>
```

Whether you create your Marker through a GeoJSON Leaflet layer group or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I ended up doing pretty much what you did, I got all relevant information from a marker inside the geojson layer, then create a new marker layer, and work with that, thank you very much for your answer,

Answer (score 1):

Every `L.Marker` has a `dragging` property, which is the marker's [`Handler`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#handler) for dragging - and Leaflet handlers can be `enable()`d and `disable()`d.

The [Leaflet documentation about `L.Marker`'s `dragging` property](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#marker-dragging) also explicitly states:

> Interaction handlers are properties of a marker instance that allow you to control interaction behavior in runtime, enabling or disabling certain features such as dragging (see `Handler` methods). Example:
>
> ```
> marker.dragging.disable();
> ```

In your specific case, this would mean something like:

```
$(document).on('click','#someButton',function(){
    layer.dragging.enable();
});
```

Be aware that this only works for `L.Marker`s - if you are using GeoJSON, do not expect this to work on lines or polygons, or on points that you specifically decided to display as `L.Circle`s or `L.CircleMarker`s (via the `pointToLayer` option of `L.GeoJSON`)