# Edit leaflet draggable option after receiving a new GeoJson object

Tags: leaflet, draggable

I'm new on using leaflet and I'm wondering how do you edit a `draggable` option for object than has already been saved in `GeoJson` and that you display later on your map.

```
pldata[index] = new L.GeoJSON(plot[i],{
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
       return new L.circleMarker(larlng, geojsonAOs)
},
    style: set_style
}).addTo(map)

pldata['aos'].eachLayer(function (layer){
    layer.options.draggable: true;
});
```

I've tried also to put the `draggable` at `true` after style but nothing happen.

P.S : Am I obligated to add `DrawItem` for just drag options ?

*P.S2* : All object have been transform in `circleMarker` or `lines` and development that has been done is quiet big so I'm trying to find a solution without break the all curent project.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet geojson update draggable state or marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156321/leaflet-geojson-update-draggable-state-or-marker)

Comment: Thanks for the informations I've already had a view about this topic and it wasn't help me so much. best regards

Comment: [`CircleMarker`s in stand-alone Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#circlemarker) don't have a `draggable` option. Are you also using Leaflet.Draw or anything like that?

Comment: Yes I'm currently using Leaflet.Draw to add new layer and be available to edit it or drag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've just update the all leaflet library and after I continue with a `eachLayer`
and on Layer

```
.on('mousedown', function(){
    map.dragging.disable();
    map.on('mousemove', function(e){
       layer.setLatLng(e.latlng)
});
```

it's working well to make a circleMarker move.